# Reactive Angular with RXJS - Auto Refresh via Subject

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to keep updated my sub menu when I adding item into my page.

I used reactive angular with subject. Inside the getmenu() I declaraide tap() which contain refreshneeded variable. But still not working. Is there any way that I make my getmenu() observable. When I declared getmenu() observable. I gives me error I can't add return variable ret.

**App-navigation.service.ts**

```
private _refreshNeeded$ = new Subject<void>();

get refreshNeeded$() {
    return this._refreshNeeded$;
}

    getmenu() = AppMenu {

var item = new AppMenuItem('Initiatives', 'Pages.WorkItems', 'far fa-calendar-alt', '');
        ret.items.splice(ret.items.indexOf(node) + 1, 0, item);
        node = item;
        this._strategiesServiceProxy.getAll("", "", 10, 0, 10, 0, "", "", 0, 1000000).subscribe(result => {
            var options = result.items.map(i => i.strategy);
            var lasti = 0;
            var gos = options.filter(go => go.growthOptionId == 1);
            var nsfs = options.filter(nsf => nsf.growthOptionId == 2);
            gos.forEach((o, i) => {
                var name = 'GO' + (i + 1) + " | " + o.name;
                name = this.text_truncate(name, 30, '...');
                node.items.push(new AppMenuItem(name, 'Pages.WorkItems', 'far fa-calendar-alt', '/app/main/gantt/' + o.id));
            });
            nsfs.forEach((o, i) => {
                var name = 'NFS' + (i + 1) + " | " + o.name;
                name = this.text_truncate(name, 30, '...');
                node.items.push(new AppMenuItem(name, 'Pages.WorkItems', 'far fa-calendar-alt', '/app/main/gantt/' + o.id));
            });
        });
}

tap(() => {
            this._refreshNeeded$.next();
        }
        );

        return ret;
    }
```

**Side-bar-menu.component.ts:**

```
    @Component({
        templateUrl: './side-bar-menu.component.html',
        selector: 'side-bar-menu',
        encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
    export class SideBarMenuComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {

        menu: AppMenu = null;

        constructor(
            injector: Injector,
            public permission: PermissionCheckerService,
            private _appSessionService: AppSessionService,
            private _uiCustomizationService: AppUiCustomizationService,
            private _appNavigationService: AppNavigationService) {
            super(injector);
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            this.menu = this._appNavigationService.getMenu();
 this._appNavigationService.refreshNeeded$
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.menu = this._appNavigationService.getMenu();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Please, show us some working sample so that we could analyze the code flow. You've presented only bit which doesn't say anything. You could use stackblitz

Comment: I already add some of my code.

Comment: There is a lot of code here, it might be easier if you gave us a more [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Right now. If I add any list from my page there is a sub menu showing the exact list but I need to reload the whole page to get the updated list. Is there any way I can get the updated list into the menu bar with reload the whole page??